# Can anyone help me with a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have never done one before and am trying to work through an online guide but I can't seem to find a good example of one with parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `calcdistance` (
    IN ulat varchar, 
    IN ulon varchar, 
    IN clat varchar, 
    IN clon varchar)
BEGIN
Select DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(ulat))
    * SIN(RADIANS(clat))
    + COS(RADIANS(ulat))
    * COS(RADIANS(clat))
    * COS(RADIANS(ulon - ulon))))) * 69.09 AS distance
END
```

the error MySQL admin gives me when I try this is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '¬† IN ulat varchar, 
¬† ¬† IN ulon varchar, 
¬† ¬† IN clat varchar, 
¬† ¬† IN cl' at line 2 (error 1064)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Anyhow, you don't 'return' the result. You could do: `SELECT DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(ulat))
    * SIN(RADIANS(clat))
    + COS(RADIANS(ulat))
    * COS(RADIANS(clat))
    * COS(RADIANS(ulon - ulon))))) * 69.09 AS distance`

Comment: I just posted the error I am getting when i try that

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS calcdistance$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `calcdistance` (IN ulat VARCHAR(50), IN ulon VARCHAR(50), IN clat VARCHAR(50), IN clon VARCHAR(50))
    BEGIN
    SELECT 
    DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(ulat)) 
    * SIN(RADIANS(clat))
    + COS(RADIANS(ulat))
    * COS(RADIANS(clat))
    * COS(RADIANS(ulon - ulon))))
    * 69.09 AS distance;


     END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: that is still giving me errors.  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS calcdistance$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `calcdista' at line 1 (error 1064)

Comment: I am assuming you are using PhpMyAdmin, and hence giving error, try using command line or sqlYog. Its working fine for me in sqlYog

Comment: I am using MySQL GUI Administrator, i can try phpmyadmin though.

Comment: just tested on PhpMyAdmin, working fine for me. Which version of MySql are you using ?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Comment: @Kyle: The stored procedure successfully created for me on MySQL 5.1.49-community, via MySQL Workbench.  How are you trying to deploy the stored procedure?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin.  I have never done a stored procedure before so maybe i am inputting it in the wrong place.  Within phpmyadmin i click my database then go to the 'sql' tab and run the stored procedure there.  I guess now that i think about it that doesnt insert it or anything.  Where should i go or what do you recommend i do?

Answer (score 0):

In your query, varchar should be varchar(255). And I think that a stored procedure should end in ; by default, unless you use DELIMITER.

Answer (score -1):

> **Great circle distance**
>
> Find the distance in kilometres between two
>   points on the surface of the earth. This is just the sort of problem
>   stored functions were made for. For a first order approximation,
>   ignore deviations of the earth's surface from the perfectly spherical.
>   Then the distance in radians is given by a number of trigonometric
>   formulas. ACOS and COS behave reasonably:

```
             COS(lat1-lat2)*(1+COS(lon1-lon2)) - COS(lat1+lat2)*(1-COS(lon1-lon2)) 
rads = ACOS( --------------------------------------------------------------------- ) 
                                              2
```

> We need to convert degrees latitude and longitude to radians, and we
>   need to know the length in km of one radian on the earth's surface,
>   which is 6378.388. The function:

```
set log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE; 

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GeoDistKM; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION GeoDistKM( lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT ) RETURNS float 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE pi, q1, q2, q3 FLOAT; 
  DECLARE rads FLOAT DEFAULT 0; 
  SET pi = PI(); 
  SET lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180; 
  SET lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180; 
  SET lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180; 
  SET lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180; 
  SET q1 = COS(lon1-lon2); 
  SET q2 = COS(lat1-lat2); 
  SET q3 = COS(lat1+lat2); 
  SET rads = ACOS( 0.5*((1.0+q1)*q2 - (1.0-q1)*q3) );  
  RETURN 6378.388 * rads; 
END; 
| 
DELIMITER ; 

-- toronto to montreal (505km): 
select geodistkm(43.6667,-79.4167,45.5000,-73.5833); 
+----------------------------------------------+ 
| geodistkm(43.6667,-79.4167,45.5000,-73.5833) | 
+----------------------------------------------+ 
|                           505.38836669921875 | 
+----------------------------------------------+
```

> (Setting `log_bin_trust_function_creators` is the most convenient way to
>   step round determinacy conventions implemented since 5.0.6.)

[Source](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1680#109)

Comment: Generally answers which contain only a single off-site link are frowned upon here.